# Angular2 retain sensitive information after browser refresh

Tags: angular, local-storage, session-storage

My login action returns information about the logged in user if they are admin or not, say `(isAdmin: true)` I can keep this information between the component until a browser refresh or similar action. But I lose this information after a browser refresh. I m confused how to retain this value.

I am using `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` to save some non-sensitive information. But this information is sensitive and the user should not be allowed to edit/view this value.

Is there any way to accomplish this using angular2?

Comment: you can store this data in a service, since services are singletons it should last for as long as the app is loaded

Comment: @OferHerman Yeah. I will keep this in an injectable service. But I have seen that this lasts as long as the browser refresh.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Have you found a solution, @PhilipJohn?

Comment: @MaxBertoli Please verify the accepted answer below. You can keep the data in a component after getting from API and pass it across the components' constructors. Once the browser is refreshed, this component should refresh the sensitive data using an API call again.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipJohn, i already have point 1 and 2, i created a isAdmin function serverside but not passing it the token. I will try and i hope it will refresh my component's ui.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would make an API call to the server or where you have the user's information each time the App starts. So, when I refresh the App I get the information from first hand and I don't have to store it in sessions, I just store the data in an object and use it.

When you login generate a token and save it in session and send it along with the API call that I mentioned earlier.

That would be my approach:

1. Login -> generate token
2. Store token
3. API call getting user's information passing token (On App init)

Hope it helps or at least gives you some valuable ideas... Let us know how you solve your issue! :D

Comment: True. This is the best solution. But I would keep the info in an injectable service until the info is lost or on browser refresh. Calling API every time a component loads is quite expensive!

Comment: @PhilipJohn No my good friend! You call API only once. Store that data in an object and then you share that data with a shared service. You make 1 call but use information in all App. Check this `shared services` to communicate between components: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: @PhilipJohn on browser refresh all data shared via shared services are wiped out. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: @PhilipJohn You can't. Or you save the data somewhere (sessionStorage, localStorage, cookies) or you trigger the methods onInit() and so the listeners will be triggered to and all the data is there when the components are initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can't trust the client. You could create an API Service that returns a boolean value if that user is an admin, and check it if the isAdmin value isn't set.

Comment: would you make this API call on every route change if you use a guard? you need to store it somewhere

Answer (score 0):

`sessionStorage` and `localStorage` should last page reloads by [design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

> while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data stored 
>   in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page 
>   session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over 
>   page reloads and restores.

You should get the data from API and store it in a service since a service is a singleton it means that it will available for the duration of the app and won't be persisted.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {
    private _isAdmin = null;

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    public get isAdmin() {
            // If we need to fetch the data
            if (_isAdmin === null) {
              return this.http.get('https://myapi.myserver.com')
                   .map((response) => response.json().isAdmin)
                   .do(isAdmin: boolean) { this._isAdmin = isAdmin);
            })
            return Observable.of(this._isAdmin);
    }
}
```

You can also use [`angular-redux`](https://github.com/angular-redux/ng-redux) or another storage library if you need to store more then just this bit of data

Comment: But does this stay even after browser refresh? I cannot keep this information in the localStorage or sessionStorage as this is sensitive. I will use this info in an Injectable service and call API for every browser refresh like @Nick said . I guess that is the best solution for my problem. Anyways thanks!

Comment: it won't stay after refresh you'll need to fetch it again. see the remark in the getter.

Answer (score 0):

I saved a user profile in localStorage and I subscribed to the router events. Then I logged the events and chose the start event of the route I was having issues with. When the event occurs I reset the user profile from localStorage which satisfies my AuthGuard checks. Now anytime I refresh, my data is still there and I don't get kicked out of guarded routes.