# Where to store client data in angular which is later used in REST-API for getting information

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, jwt, local-storage

I have an angular application, Whenever a user logs in I get all his data along with a jsonwebtoken from server through REST-API request and store it in localstorage.

After that I use the same user data such as `email, account_status, id` etc  in other REST-API calls for getting more information. This is obviously not the correct way to do, The user can modify his `localstorage` data and get other user's information easily.

I am using `jsonwebtoken` for authentication, verifying the token in `authgaurd service` through REST-API call.

Can anybody suggest the correct way to store the information with brief description.
Can I use Cookies for the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 retain sensitive information after browser refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234724/angular2-retain-sensitive-information-after-browser-refresh)

Comment: you're basically trying to implement a JWT session. the only REAL reason to use them is if you need to support non-web apps, or using more than one back-end server. do read: [stop-using-jwt-for-sessions](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions) sadly, any other scenario, in the long run, you better off with a normal cookie based session.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `shared service` and import in `app module` , use it in all components ,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { MyWrapper } from '../models/models';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService{

  data:any={};

  setData(key,value) {
     this.data[key]=value;
  }

  clearData() {
     this.data={};
  }

  getData(key) {
    return this.data[key];
  }

}
```

Note : This is will not work exactly as local storage, you'll lose data once the browser closed or page refreshed kind of session storage, but still you can put and get data across components.

To set data,

```
 sharedService.setData("mydata","mydata");
```

To get data,

```
 sharedService.getData("mydata");
```

If you want the data to be persistent then  alternative ways are you can store the data in the server and get the data in `ngOnInit` or use some kind of encryption(`jsencrypt` or `cryptojs`) when storing the data in local storage so user wont able to modify it.Still it will not be a bullet proof solution.If you are storing some sensitive data , I would recommend you to store it in server.

Comment: But the data stored will not be persistent using the service, it would be cleared when the user closes the browser.

Comment: Yes ,kind of session storage. Or else you need to store it server side and get the in data ngoninit. Or you may use some encryption to prevent users changes the data in local storage.

Comment: This method looks good, but can you suggest what are the ways commonly used for this issue.

Comment: Which method? @RakeshSenwar

Comment: where would you then hold the key to that encryption ? in the storage also right ? and since its javascript, can easily be back traced and there goes your data safety

Comment: My idea is to just stop the user from changing  the value not to provide security solutions. Anyway we can build a little algorithm   in js obfuscate the code, still we can't provide bullet proof solutions.@Stavm

Answer (score 0):

If your application logic is complex, you can consider adopting some form of state management, based on the Flux architecture. The most common and well established state management solution is [NgRx Store](https://ngrx.io/), and it is very similar to Redux, which may be familiar with you if you have worked with React.js.

Comment: But the data stored will not be persistent using the ngrx store, it would be cleared when the user closes the browser. Can you please elaborate it more

Comment: @RakeshSenwar I didn't know you need the data to persist upon closing of the browser. In that case, I would recommend localStorage instead..